# Embed ascii diagram in groff?

Tags: text-formatting, ascii, groff, roff

I have groff file to generate a pdf in the format:

```
.TL
Article title
.AU
Author name
.AI
Publication title
.SH
.LP
First paragraph
.PP
More paragraphs
```

I'm then running `groff -ms a.ms  -T pdf > a.pdf` to generate a pdf. I like how groff makes formatting easy but I'm wondering if it would be possible to include an ascii diagram.

For example the following:

```
 +-------------------------+             +-----------------+
 |                         |             |                 |
 |      Hello              |             |                 |
 |                         +-------------+                 |
 |                         |             |                 |
 +-------------------------+             +-----------------+
```

If input as a normal paragraph turns into:

[image]

Is there anyway I can insert a section into groff that will preserve the spaces so these kind of diagrams can be used?

Looking at the [manual for `groff_ms`](https://linux.die.net/man/7/groff_ms) I see:

> .PS and .PE Denotes a graphic, to be processed by the pic
>   preprocessor. You can create a pic file by hand, using the AT&T pic
>   manual available on the Web as a reference, or by using a graphics
>   program such as xfig.

But this seems to only accept [pic language markup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pic_language).

Is there anyway I can insert assci drawings into groff?

Comment: you have to choose monospaced font for the ascii art

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Groff supports a `CW` (constant width) font, and you can select it with `.ft CW` or `\f(CW`.

To turn off filling, use a display, `.DS` - `.DE`, or a `.nf` - `.fi` pair.

```
.TL
Two boxes, two ways
.LP
ASCII drawing
.DS C
.ft CW
 +-------------------------+             +-----------------+
 |                         |             |                 |
 |      Hello              |             |                 |
 |                         +-------------+                 |
 |                         |             |                 |
 +-------------------------+             +-----------------+
.ft
.DE
.LP
Pic drawing
.PS
box width 2 "\f(CWHello\fP"
line 1.5
box width 1.5
.PE
```

[image: troff postscript output]

Comment: Very nice. Don't see much *roff formatting in the public eye these days

Comment: The nice thing is that `nroff` manages to draw the pic boxes fairly nicely in ASCII too.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this is to make the block centered DS like below

```
.DS B
.ft CW
                     +-------------+     +------------+
                     |             |     |            |
                     |             |     |            |
                     |             |     +-+----------+
                     +-------------+       |
    +------------+         +-+             |          +--------------+
    |            |         |           +---+          |              |
    |            |         |           |              |              |
    |            |         |           |              +--+-----------+
    +------+-----+     +---+-----------+----------+      |
           |           |                          |      |
           +-----------+                          +------+
                       |                          |
                       |                          +------------+
    +------------------+                          |            |
    |                  +--------------------------+         +--+----------+
+---+---------+                                             |             |
|             |                                             |             |
|             |                                             +-------------+
+-------------+

.ft
.DE
```